# Error message when trying to write a xlsx.-file with R

Tags: java, eclipse, r, xlsx, statet

I try to save some R-dataframes into .xlsx-files using the `write.xlsx` function of the `xlsx` package like this

```
write.xlsx(tab,file="test",sheetName="testsheet",col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,append=FALSE)
```

whereas the object `tab` is a data frame, as prooved here

```
> class(tab)
[1] "data.frame"
```

When I run the code I get the following error message

```
>  write.xlsx(tab,file="test.xlsx",sheetName="testsheet",col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,append=FALSE)
Fehler in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Z", "hasField", .jcast(x, "java/lang/Object"),  : 
  RcallMethod: cannot determine object class
```

and I have no particular idea what the problem could be.

PS: I'm running R 2.14.1 in the StatET 2.0 plugin in Eclipse 3.7 on a 64bit machine.

Comment: Are you using `RTerm` or `rj` in Eclipse?

Comment: `rj`! Can this be the Problem?

Comment: Yes, it could. Try your code in `RTerm`.  (I can't remember the details how I made `xlsx` work, but it's worth a try.)

Comment: Maybe you're right! It works when I run the code with TinnR... curiouser and curiouser... or do you even know why? I'd be very interested!

Comment: I have never tried to figure out why, but several things don't work properly in `rj`. This includes all use of `RCOM` as well as printing of the return value of `system()`.  I use `rj` by default because I like the way it deals with help, but if things don't work, I try it in `RTerm`. One day I'll have some spare time and I'll take it up with the author.

Comment: @Andrie: post comments as an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you. Have complied :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work in Eclipse, you can start R using either `rj` - a Java terminal, or `RTerm` - the native R terminal.

If you are using the `rj` terminal and something doesn't work, try the same thing with `RTerm`.

I have never tried to figure out why, but a few things don't work properly in `rj`. This includes all use of `RCOM` as well as printing of the return value of `system()`.

I use `rj` by default because I like the way it deals with help (amongst other benefits).
But if things don't work, I try it in `RTerm`. One day I'll have some spare time and I'll take it up with the author.

---

PS. I want to stress that I absolutely love StatET in Eclipse.  These oddities or `rj` are very minor inconveniences in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: I  **`<3`**  StatET/Eclipse too (noticed it again when doint the stuff in TinnR -> doesn't even know code folding...)

Answer (score 2):

From my experience these kind of errors are produced when the standard rj package is installed instead of the one supplied bij the StatET developer.
Check the installation guide here:
http://www.walware.de/goto/statet

If you would happen to be using Debian or Ubuntu, you can also use the repository from OpenAnalytics to install StatET and the correct rj packages in one go.

http://deb.openanalytics.eu/howto.html

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. **Two** codes work with my problem:

**FIRST) Convert vector to dataframe:**

library(xlsx)
data <- data.frame(c(1,2,3))
write.xlsx(data, file = "C:/Users/Name/Downloads/data.xlsx")

**SECOND) Use another library:**

`# Using openxlsx package
library(openxlsx)
dataD1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3))
write.xlsx(dataD1, "C:/Users/Name/Downloads/dataD1.xlsx")

I hope you have solved your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).